# Most Efficient Way to Display the Date Only in Datetime Column and Then Convert it Into Varchar after

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, select, varchar

I want to display a column with a data type of `datetime` as `varchar`. But I don't need the time to be displayed. This is what I'm currently using

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(date, [Date_Created])) AS 'Date_Created'
FROM 
    Accounts_Table
```

Is there are more efficient or rather less CPU extensive in doing this?

Comment: Thats a trivial operation - why are you worried about efficiency for that? If you are worried, you should carry out your formatting in your front end - which is the normal place to do it.

Comment: the date displayed will be used in a parameter by a method created using C#. I was not the one that created the method in C# and since the date type for the method to be used is string, I also have no power to change the data type for method. So I have no choice but to adapt, I am trying to convince the guy that created the method to change it tho.

Comment: Fair enough, but why did you think there would be any performance issues with such a simple query?

Comment: I was gonna run this with other queries and columns, but I had a weird feeling that there would be a better way of doing this specific part but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: You do have an answer below.

Comment: `the date displayed will be used in a parameter by a method created using C#` Well, you can still return `date` or `datetime` and do the conversion to string in `c#`.

Answer (score 5):

You may try:

```sql
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date_Created], 120) AS [Date_Created]
FROM Accounts_Table;
```

The format mask for 120 is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`, and by using `varchar(10)` in the conversion, we only retain the first 10 characters, which is the date portion only.  My approach is still calling `CONVERT`, but at least it avoids the nested calls which you were making.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `Convert()` with a style has been the normal approach for a long time, I believe that we now have a better option: `Format()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

```sql
SELECT Format(Date_Created, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Date_Created
FROM   Accounts_Table
;
```

I think that this approach is better as the intention is easier to understand (`yyyy-MM-dd` is clearly intended, where `120` is something that has to be looked up).

Answer (score 0):

try casting the datetime as a date then cast the date as a varchar string

```
  select cast(cast(getDate() as date) as varchar) string_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),LEFT('2021-25-01 06:13:18.430',10)) As 'Date_Created'
```